# Symfony form: disable "required" for a field from Twig

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I'm trying to disable the frontend HTML5 validation for a filed in a form built in Symfony.

In Twig, i use this code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control input-lg','novalidate': 'novalidate}}) }}
```

but the field is still considered as required.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you set it on the form itself, rather than the "email" field ?

Comment: I want the single field not required, not the entire form...

Comment: @Aerendir - I'm not implying you to do the same but I would always accept the first answer if the rest do exactly the same thing. If I don't then I would add a comment explaining why. No hard feelings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set that in your form type to disable the field validation.

```
->add('test', null, array(
    'required' => false
))
```

If you want to disable it for the whole field you can try something like this:

```
{{ form_start(form, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}
```

Comment: I want the single field not required, not the entire form, so the twig solution you suggested doesn't fit my needs.

Trying to set required => false seems not working, also if the documentation suggests the same approach o.O

Comment: I use that in all my forms and its working well... are you sure that you have set the 'required' correctly?

Comment: My fault: i wasn't using the formtype but i was creating it directly in the controller. Those methods all work well! Thank you!

Comment: ah ok =) then have fun.

Comment: @Stony - +1 You got it :)

Answer (score 5):

You can just do this in twig:

```
{{ form_start(form, { attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'} }) }}
```

Or you can do this in your formtype class:

```
->add('name', 'text', ['required' => false])
```

**EDIT:**

In example below, only `name` field will trigger html5 validation.

Formclass

```
->add('name', 'text')
->add('middlename', 'text', ['required' => false])
```

Twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
    <p>NAME: {{ form_widget(form.name) }}</p>
    <p>MIDDLENAME: {{ form_widget(form.middlename) }}</p>

    <p><button name="button">Submit</button></p>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Comment: As commented above, i want the single field not required, not the entire form... Thank you anyway for your reply!

Comment: Then use the second option showed in answer and don't apply it to other fileds.

Comment: Is the same approach suggested by the documentation, but it seems not work and I don't know why...

Comment: Look at the example above please.

Comment: My fault: i wasn't using the formtype but i was creating it directly in the controller. Those methods all work well! Thank you!